# Increase alert (locally) when beamercounter increases

Tags: beamer, overlays

Sometimes in an item I increase the beamer counter, which controls when text is uncovered. I'd like to affect "alert" at the same time.

For example, I often do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<alert@+|+->]{Using information under uncertainty}
\begin{itemize}
\item One item.
\item<alert@+-.(2)|+-> What is the answer to this fascinating question? \uncover<+->{\textcolor{green}{A (fascinating) answer}, but I want the question
still alerted in addition to this part.}
\item Another item.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I like this PDF output.

I am looking for a way to achieve the same PDF output, but without having to specify the `<alert@+-.(2)|+->`. That is, I'm looking for a way for alert to be automatically adjusted according to when the beamercounter is increased in the item.

EDIT: Ideally, I think I would like to switch this alert-automatically-adapting behavior on/off at the itemize level and/or the document level (i.e., preamble). However, if I can at least remove that hardcoded `2` I would already be happier. That is, if I have multiple uncovers in the same itemize, I currently need to adapt `2` accordingly. If I still have to specify something for each `\item` where I want this behavior, as long as I could do something like ``<alert@+-.(Q)|+->` where Q is automatically replaced accordingly, that would be a nice improvement.